# Is waiting for data from a server an acceptable iOS background task?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, background-process

I'm confused about the [Apple requirements](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) for a long running background task.

> For tasks that require more execution time to implement, you must
>   request specific permissions to run them in the background without
>   their being suspended. In iOS, only specific app types are allowed to
>   run in the background:
>
> Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background,
>   such as a music player app
>
> Apps that record audio content while in the background
>
> Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as
>   a navigation app
>
> Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
>
> Apps that need to download and process new content regularly
>
> Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories
>
> Apps that implement these services must declare the services they
>   support and use system frameworks to implement the relevant aspects of
>   those services.   Declaring the services lets the system know which
>   services you use, but in some cases it is the system frameworks that
>   actually prevent your application from being suspended.

All I want is to get a JSON response from my server and display a notification like "You have a new message". So it has to work if the app is in background.

I'm looking for something like a service in Android, but I know Apple doesn't allow that because of concerns about the battery life, except for those app types.

Does this item cover what I want to do?

> Apps that need to download and process new content regularly

Comment: I think your app will likely get rejected if you try to repeatedly poll for new messages in the background state. Fruity Geek's solution is the best you'll get, but really you should just implement push notifications.

Comment: @AaronBrager Ok thank you Aaron but would it get rejected even if I ask only for a few seconds every 30 minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement push notifications. They support JSON payloads

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html

You can implement a client-side version of this. Apps that need to check for new content periodically can ask the system to wake them up so that they can initiate a fetch operation for that content. To support this mode, enable the Background fetch option from the Background modes section of the Capabilities tab in your Xcode project. (You can also enable this support by including the `UIBackgroundModes` key with the `fetch` value in your app’s Info.plist file.) Enabling this mode is not a guarantee that the system will give your app any time to perform background fetches. The system must balance your app’s need to fetch content with the needs of other apps and the system itself. After assessing that information, the system gives time to apps when there are good opportunities to do so.

When a good opportunity arises, the system wakes or launches your app into the background and calls the app delegate’s `application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:` method. Use that method to check for new content and initiate a download operation if content is available. As soon as you finish downloading the new content, you must execute the provided completion handler block, passing a result that indicates whether content was available. Executing this block tells the system that it can move your app back to the suspended state and evaluate its power usage. Apps that download small amounts of content quickly, and accurately reflect when they had content available to download, are more likely to receive execution time in the future than apps that take a long time to download their content or that claim content was available but then do not download anything.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to avoid push notifications because it's more complicated server side.

Comment: I would like a client side solution if possible because  I can't really change the server side.

Comment: Edited my answer with client-side solution.

Comment: Thank you. It's exactly what I needed! Is there a risk that my app get rejected because of that?

Comment: @Marc No, but with this approach there's no guarantee your app's background handler will get called frequently enough for your needs.